# Разделить строку с большим количеством пробелов

Tags: python, строки, list, split

Имеется строка, например - `"apple banana onion         cucumber milk   1   139"`

Необходимо разделить строку и сделать из нее список только в тех местах где более одного пробела.

Должно получится так - `["apple banana onion", "cucumber milk", "1", "139"]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

print( re.split(r"\s\s+", "apple banana onion         cucumber milk   1   139") )
```

`\s` — space, пробельный символ. `+` — один или больше повторений подряд.

Comment: Работает и так, но только потому что парсер Питона вас очень уважает и игнорирует несуществующую escape-последовательность `\s`. Лучше писать `"\\s\\s+"` или `r"\s\s+"`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Упс, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
line = "apple banana onion         cucumber milk   1   139"

print([i.strip() for i in line.split("  ") if i ])
```

Comment: Излишне сложно )